# dynamixel_motor stack on Fuerte in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, dynamixel-motor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've just performed a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04.
After installing ROS Fuerte (following the installation instructions), I tried to install the dynamixel_motor stack.

I can't seem to find it.
On the website (http://ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_motor), it says it should be possible to run:
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-dynamixel-motor

However, when I try to do so, I get the "Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-dynamixel-motor" message.

Does such stack exist in the Ubuntu package repo, or should I checkout the code from the svn?

Thanks a lot guys!

Murilo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35274/dynamixel_motor-stack-on-fuerte-in-ubuntu-12.04/) by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on ROS Answers with karma: 806 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2012-05-30**:
oops... clearly I didn't search enough... sorry about the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate of my previous question: http://answers.ros.org/question/33985/dynamixel_motor-debs-in-fuerte/

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2012-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1